# Finding Per Month recurrence with the same weekdays with moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm new to moment.js but I'm trying to generate dates that are recurring every month on the same weekdays not following the date. Example, An Event on the 2nd Tuesday of every month. I saw the moment-recur but I'm having a hard time making it work.

This is the code I have so far. Start Date is a hardcoded date fyi

```
var firstDay = new Date(startDate);

var nextMonth = new Date(
  firstDay.getFullYear(),
  firstDay.getMonth() + 1,
  firstDay.getDate()
);

console.log(startDate);
console.log(nextMonth);
console.log(firstDay);

var next = moment
  .recur()
  .every(startDate)
  .daysOfWeek()
  .every(nextMonth)
  .weeksOfMonthByDay();

return moment(next).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Comment: How many valid dates are you looking to get returned? Just the next instance? Or the next 5? The next 'n' dates? Because according to the  moment-recur docs you might want to use something else: "These functions may be very inefficient/slow. They work by attempting to match every date from the start of a range until the desired number of dates have been generated"

Comment: If you want to get back a lot of reoccuring dates you might want to look into [CRON statements/scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).  The CRON statement for every second Tuesday would be '0 0 12 ? 1/1 TUE#2 *' - Something like [later.js](https://github.com/bunkat/later) or [node-cron's nextDates function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) might work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using moment-recur. I have made it a function so it a bit clearer how you can change the params to get different dates. You may still want to look into CRON to generate dates for yourself depending on your needs.

```js
function getNextEvents(startDate, numEvents, dayOfWeek, weekIndex) {
  var events = moment(startDate)
              .recur()
              .every(dayOfWeek)
              .daysOfWeek()
              .every(weekIndex)
              .weeksOfMonthByDay();
  
  return events.next(numEvents, "YYYY-MM-DD");
}

let firstDay = new Date();
var nextMonth = new Date(
  firstDay.getFullYear(),
  firstDay.getMonth() + 1,
  firstDay.getDate()
);

// Every second tuesday of the month: get next 5 dates
console.log(getNextEvents(nextMonth, 5, "Tuesday", 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-recur/1.0.7/moment-recur.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: very nice answer, but why assign `events` as intermediate variable? Why not just `return moment().recur(). ... .weeksOfMonthByDay().next(...)`?

Comment: @user633183 Chaining the next call in would be cleaner but I wanted it to be clear which calls created the moment-recur object they were looking for, so I separated them from the call that extracted"valid dates" from that object.